# How do I get an article with all of it's tags when searching on tags?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
select ...,
group_concat(tag.string separator '|') as tags
from article a
left join articletag on a.id = articletag.a_id
left join tag on tag.id = articletag.t_id
where /* OR product of (column like %term%) */
group by a.id
```

The problem is that when a match occurs on a tag, it breaks my 'grouping' and returns only one row.

How do I get the whole group when at least 1 row matches without huge performance penalties?

---

example:

```
article
id | title      | content
2  | article 2  | long content

tag
id | string
1  | tag 1
2  | tag 2
4  | tag 4

articletag
a_id | t_id
2    | 1
2    | 2
2    | 4
```

the current query will return `(2, 'article 2', 'long content', 'tag 1')` when it contains `tag.string like '%tag 1%'`.

or `(2, 'article 2', 'long content', 'tag 1|tag 2')` when searching for `'tag 2'`

I want to get `(2, 'article 2', 'long content', 'tag 1|tag 2|tag 4')`

Comment: Some sample data would go a long way here.

Comment: I tried to write it more general, but I'll edit now to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that you are grouping by the `id` column of the `article` table, but you are selecting non aggregate records while also using `GROUP BY`.  This is somewhat hidden in your original query beacuse you only have ellipsis `...`, but the problem is there.

Instead, compute the pipe-separated tag string in a separate subquery, and then join this back to the `article` table:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.tags
FROM article t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT at.a_id,
           GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(t.string, 'NA') ORDER BY t.string SEPARATOR '|') AS tags
    FROM articletag at
    LEFT JOIN tag t
        ON at.t_id = t.id
    GROUP BY at.a_id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.a_id
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thanks lots! Btw, do you happen to know what are the performance implications, at least when comparing what I had vs subquery?

Comment: Tricky question.  If you _only_ wanted the `id` and the concatenated string, your original query should have worked.  In my answer, there would basically be an additional table scan to join the non correlated subquery back to the `article` table.  This is relatively minor, and in any case your original approach is not really an option if you want other fields from `article`.